# Excel 2010 VBA - Move Starting Point of Macro?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

Hi Everyone (first post bear with me lol), I've gotten a macro written that does exactly what I need it to do EXCEPT I cannot figure out how to get the macro to start in Sheet1 at a different cell. It's currently posting the information I need in cell B3 but I'd like it to start in cell B10. Thoughts?

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B600").ClearContents

    For i = 1 To 30
generate:

        RowNum = Application.RoundUp(Rnd() * 88, 0)

        If Application.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet1").[B:B], _
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(RowNum, "A")) = 0 Then

            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2).Value = _
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(RowNum, "A").Value
        Else
            GoTo generate
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Change Offset(2) to Offset(9).

Comment: Hi Bandersnatch, I want to keep the spacing between my results with an Offset of 2. If I change to 9, it does move my start point down, but also causes my results to be spaced 9 rows apart. So I'd like to keep the spacing between results, but move the first result to a different cell. Hopefully that helps clarify!

Answer (score 0):

Use this

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Button1_Click()
    Const RNG = "B2:B600"   '<--- Range on Sheet1 --------------------
    Const OFFSET_ROW = 2
    Const START_ROW = 10    '<--- Start row --------------------------

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet:   Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet:   Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Dim r As Long, ws2val As String

    ws1.Range(RNG).ClearContents

    For r = START_ROW To 30 * OFFSET_ROW + START_ROW - 1 Step OFFSET_ROW

        ws2val = ws2.Cells(Application.RoundUp(Rnd() * 88, 0), "A").Value

        If Application.CountIf(ws1.Range(RNG), ws2val) = 0 Then
            ws1.Range("B" & r).Value = ws2val
        Else
            r = r - OFFSET_ROW
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Test Data in **Sheet2**, and Result on **Sheet1**
(Output starts on Row 10 as you intended)

[image: Sheet1] [image: Sheet2]

Comment: Hi Paul, I tried to use this but it froze excel. Additionally, the code does exactly what I'd like it too except that I'd simply like to start my entire results section in a specific cell. Thoughts?

Comment: Hi Toolman, I don't have access to your data, but with what I used it works as expected - see the 2 images in the answer. You can also easily change the START_ROW (at the top) to a different value. Let me know if there are any other issues